# Class property inside another Class in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I write one class property into another class in Nodejs? For example, Participant Node has an RTRMapping array in its class. How can i write this type of code in Nodejs? Or javascript?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJxIX.png)

Comment: Types in JavaScript are loose and there is no way to specify that an array should only contain a certain type. TypeScript does have this static typing ability. Alternatively, you could create your own class that works as an array and only accepts certain types at run-time. You could just use a normal array and by sheer intent only put RTRMapping instances in it, but JavaScript Array and most of JavaScript in general does not support static type requirements to prevent you from putting something else in there if you tried.